# 3 internet connections of the same origin

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

Does anybody have a solution or idea of how i can make my computer not connect to my wireless without it making 2 other connections to the same network ?

Comment: What connections? A screenshot would be beneficial.

Comment: What? Could you explain your question in more detail?

Comment: Im sorry i didn't upload any screenshot. It look's like there are 2 connections or more to the same network example: wifi_1, and wifi_2
wich connects to the same network, have tried alot of simple stuff like disconnecting and reconnecting and such, deleting the wifi settings etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue like this at one point. I ended up uninstalling the driver, and reinstalling it with the software.

You can also try disabling and restarting wireless zero configuration in services.msc. I've heard that that can fix wireless issues similar to the one you're describing.

Comment: :O ill try it, thx !